# What is the difference between using the colon and as syntax for declaring type?

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between the `:` syntax for declaring type

```
let serverMessage: UServerMessage = message;
```

and the `as` syntax

```
let serverMessage = message as UServerMessage;
```

They seem to produce the same result in this example at least

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The first one is a type annotation. The second one is a type assertion.

The type annotation tells the compiler check that the assignment is fully valid and that `message` is indeed compatible with `UServerMessage`

The type assertion tells the compiler, I know what I'm doing, `message` is a `UServerMessage`, never mind what you think you know, I have more information and I know best. Some checks are still performed even if you use type assertions so you might see double assertions `message as any as UServerMessage` for example if the type of `message` is very incompatible with `UServerMessage`

You should always prefer a type annotation to an assertion. Use assertion with care and only if you have to. A type assertion is a hammer to get a square peg to fit into a round hole, useful at times but you might take a second look at what you are doing to make sure its right. Make sure it's not:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Yes they are different

Firstly, let's see this example

```
let a: string;
let b: number;

function c() {
    const d = (a || b) as number; // Works
    const e: number = (a || b); // Throw typing error
}
```

so `as number` telling Typescript that in that case, the value will be a number (***define the type of the result***). It forces Typescript to think that it will always return a number (*even that it could be not true*).

``: number``` ***define the type of the variable***, not the result. So Typescript will verify and ensure that there could not be another case (*Even that it could never happen*).

Hope that help.