# Type assertions in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have just started learning typescript and have come across a concept called type assertions in typescript. What I have understood is that they behave just like typecasting but we are basically asserting the type of a variable at compile time instead of leaving the part at run time(type casting).
The doubt is that when I do, say something like this:

```
var v1: number = <number><any>"1001";
```

And then do:

```
console.log(typeof v1);
```

,it gives me the output as `string`. 
How is my data type getting changed?

Edit: What I meant to say by "after type asserting" was that, continuing the above example, if I do

```
console.log(typeof v1++);
```

,gives me as number

And If I do:

```
console.log(typeof (v1+"1001"));
```

,gives me as string

Thanks!

Comment: It's not changed: the value remains exactly the same, you just tell a compiler to trust you and treat a value as if it was a particular type (but it does not and cannot check if it's true). I personally did not find use for it, and in my codebases I never use it.

Comment: @zerkms Does that mean the type that I have explicitly defined is never taken into consideration? Will it always be the type of the value that "I am converting"?

Comment: Yep, it's you're "lying" to a compiler about the type and it does not have chance to check it :-)

Comment: You might find this useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54684886/what-is-the-difference-between-using-the-colon-and-as-syntax-for-declaring-type/54685761#54685761

Comment: But I have one more thing to ask. That is, I have also noticed that the data type changes based on certain operations that I perform on it after type asserting. That is the data type changes to number when I use a post increment/decrement operator and so on. Does that mean the compiler has then found a way to check the type automatically?

Comment: "after type asserting" --- after you asserted a type - compiler assumes that type is correct and all the other operations on this value consider that type only. If you provide a particular example (please edit your question for that, not comments) we would be able to explain it specifically.

Comment: @zerkms I have edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: "How is my data type getting changed?" --- it's not changed. `typeof` is a runtime javascript operation. You had always had a string there. `typeof v1++` returns you a number because `++`'ing a string returns you a number.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks! You have been a much help.